# Double integral problem with specific region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $D$ denotes area of the first quadrant which bounded by two lines $y=0, y=x$ and

two hyperbolas $xy=1, x^2-y^2=1$.

Evaluate double integral
$$\iint_D \frac{x^4-y^4}{1+xy}dxdy$$

---

Since we can't integrate this neither $x$ nor $y$, should do $u, v$ substitution.

General problem which like this has similar bounds so I can find change of variables easily.

(For example :

If I have these bounds :
$$x+y=1, x+y=3\\ x-y=1, x-y=3$$

I can find $x+y=u, \quad x-y=v$ easily. )

But the original problem is, there is no similar bounds So I don't know what should I $uv-$sub.

The only thing what can I find is given two hyperbolas are same but rotated $\frac{\pi}{4}$. (or $-\frac{\pi}{4}$).

Is there any hints?

If I do $$xy=u \\
x^2-y^2=v$$

then$$
dxdy=\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}dudv$$

So the original double integral changes to $$\frac{1}{2}\iint_{D*} \frac{v}{1+u}dudv$$

But In this case, I can't find the bound of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider your second approach: note that the map $$(u,v)=\Phi(x,y)=(xy,x^2-y^2)$$
transforms bijectively
$$D=\{(x,y): 0\leq xy\leq 1, 0\leq x^2-y^2\leq 1,x\geq 0\}$$
into $D^*=[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

[image]

Therefore, since $dxdy=\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}dudv$, it follows that
$$\iint_{D} \frac{x^4-y^4}{1+xy}dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\iint_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} \frac{v}{1+u}dudv=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{v^2}{2}\right]_0^1\left[\ln(1+u)\right]_0^1=\frac{\ln(2)}{4}.$$